# how to set the limits of (x,y) coordinates for the character movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>animate demo</title>

  <style>

  div {

    position: absolute;
    margin: 30px;
  }

  </style>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body background="./images/RectTrack1.jpg">




<button id="left">&laquo;</button>

<button id="right">&raquo;</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="up">up</button>

<button id="down">down</button>

<!-- <div class="block"></div> -->





<div class="block" >

<img src="./images/vijaya.png" />

 </div>

<script>

$( "#right" ).click(function() 

{
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px"},"slow" );

}); 
$( "#up" ).click(function() {

      $( ".block" ).animate({ "bottom": "+=50px"},"slow" );

    }); 
$( "#down" ).click(function() {

      $( ".block" ).animate({ "bottom": "-=50px" }, "slow" );

    }); 


$( "#left" ).click(function(){

  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );

});

</script>



</body>


</html>
```

-------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<_----------------------------------

in this code I want to set the coordinate limits...
I'm actually trying to make a simple game using javascript...In this set of code there is a simple track which I have made using canvas  and I'm trying to move a character on that track...I'm able to move the character in 4 directions(up,down,left,right)..

but I'm facing two problems in this code..

1)once I press the 'up' key, the character is going directly to the bottom of the track then it starts moving towards the 'up' direction..

2)I'm not able to set the limits of the coordinates.. the character can go out of the track.

Anyone has an idea of why that is and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the "left" and "bottom" css properties. So, on first click, these need to be calculated, and that's where you get the "blink".

My proposal is that you abandon the idea of "bottom" and use "top". Much more logical. Then initialize the "top" and "left" css properties so that you avoid the "blink".

Here is a working sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>animate demo</title>

  <style>

  div {

    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 80px;
  }

  </style>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body background="./images/RectTrack1.jpg">




<button id="left">«</button>

<button id="right">»</button>  
<button id="up">up</button>

<button id="down">down</button>

<!-- <div class="block"></div> -->





<div class="block" >

<img src="./images/vijaya.png" />

 </div>

<script>
  
  var limits = {
    left:300,
    top:300
    },
      increment = 50,
      moving = {
        left:false,
        top:false
        }
  function releaseMove(prop){
    moving[prop] = false;
    }
  function doMove(up,prop){
    var b = $(".block");
    var pv = parseInt(b.css(prop));
    if(up && pv+increment>limits[prop]){
      alert(pv+increment+" too much");
      return;
      }
    if(!up && pv-increment<0){
      alert(pv-increment+" too small");
      return;
      }
    if(moving[prop]){
      return;
      }
    moving[prop] = true;
    var animobj = {};
    animobj[prop] = (up ? "+" : "-")+"="+increment+"px";
    b.animate(animobj,"slow",releaseMove.bind(null,prop));
    }

$( "#right" ).click(doMove.bind(null,true,"left")); 
$( "#left" ).click(doMove.bind(null,false,"left"));
$( "#up" ).click(doMove.bind(null,false,"top")); 
$( "#down" ).click(doMove.bind(null,true,"top")); 



</script>



</body>


</html>
```

Now, when it comes about limiting the values - laziness is a virtue of the educated :)
Here is a nice example of using the "bind" feature of functions.

Comment: hey  Andrija, we are facing one more problem ...from the start point character is  directly moving down..it should not move dat way..1st it should follow the horizontal track then it should come down .

Comment: Hey, ajay, seems that I missed a point in your idea. If your press "down" it should go down, right?

Comment: yeah, but my wish is that it've to go 775px in X-direction (775,0) and at 775 px, it have to go down Y-direction(775,350).. but it's also  going down from starting point  
eg.    img..............................>(775,0)
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        v(775,350)
  like this .. can u help me ??